# how to erase empty cells in a tableView

Tags: swift, tableview, ios8, cells

I am trying to display a simple UITableView with some data so that it doesn't displays empty cells at the end of the table. How do I set an empty footer view in swift?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to remove the separator. Set the `separatorStyle` of the tableView to `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone`.

Answer (score 1):

adding an empty footer view?!

```
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRectZero);
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = view;
```

Comment: You don't even need to give the view a frame... that way you wont get the extra 100pts at the bottom of the tableView

Comment: true - my bad I was setting it randomly.